# How to get global index in devexpress datagrid with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, devexpress

I'm working with DevExpress DataGrid on React.js.
According to [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/yvmv4) example, I can navigate to specific row that not visible within a specific key.
But in this example, it use the "focusedRowKey" property.
In my case, I use the "focusedRowIndex" property.
 My problem is that I want to navigate to specific row by index that is not visible.
Is there any "navigateToRow" function that receive index, and not key?
Or can I get the global index, like "getRowIndexByKey" (this function not good for me, if the index is outside the visible rows, it return -1).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by manipulating between them:

```
let value = null;

// eslint-disable-next-line default-case
switch (fieldType) {
  case 'focusedRowIndex':
    value = eventIndex;
    break;
  case 'focusedRowKey':
    value = eventId;
    break;
}

const obj = {
  [fieldType]: value
};
```

And then, on the component itself:

```
        <DataGrid
          id='grid-container'
          dataSource={events}
          keyExpr='_Id'
          showBorders={true}
          focusedRowEnabled={true}
          {...obj}
```